# Error when I send email using Office365 in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, office365

In Laravel 7, I want to send email from my application using Office365, tried email password and app password none worked.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=my-email-here
MAIL_PASSWORD=my-email-password-here
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=my-email-here
MAIL_FROM_NAME="App name"
```

In the above code **MAIL_PASSWORD** is my email password not app password
this configuration gives me the following error

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "support@tingsapp.com" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "451", with message "451 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX4  [MRXP264CA0044.FRAP264.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MRXP264CA0044.FRAP264.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

In the second try I put App Password created in office.com as **MAIL_PASSWORD** value, but I get same error.

after changing the .env I run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`

Is there anything I missed, please

Answer (score 1):

you need to put the password in double-quotes.

*Replace: MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
With: MAIL_PASSWORD="yourpassword"*

after changing the .env just run:

*php artisan cache:clear*

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your email instead of password on MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS like this

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=my-email-here
MAIL_PASSWORD=my-email-password-here
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=my-email-here
MAIL_FROM_NAME="App name"
```

or you can use smtp-mail.outlook.com as MAIL_HOST

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp-mail.outlook.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=my-email-here
MAIL_PASSWORD=my-email-password-here
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=my-email-here
MAIL_FROM_NAME="App name"
```

Comment: Thanks @Yudiz for replying, MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS actually has my email not my email password that was a copy paste mistake. but I'll try your second solution.

Comment: I get same error, ```Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "support@tingsapp.com" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [ZR0P278CA0107.CHEP278.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [ZR0P278CA0107.CHEP278.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
".```.

Comment: this is the .env,  ```MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp-mail.outlook.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=support@tingsapp.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=my-password-which-I-login-to-office.com
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=support@tingsapp.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Tings App"```.   It works using gmail.